# Windows Virtual Desktop why I need an AD sync to Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

why I need a sync from onpremise AD to Azure AD for azure windows virtual desktop? It stands in the requierments but I do not understand the details why.

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Virtual desktop is at time not compatible to run in a cloud only environment with Azure Active Directory only.

There are two options supported.

```
•   Local AD synced with AAD connect to Azure AD
```

If you already are using a local active directory synced with Azure Ad Connect to Azure AD. This is probably your first choice of setup. You will need to add an Azure VPN to connect your LAN to an Azure Network. The WVD hosts need access to a Domain controller. For the best performance and functions, I also recommend setup of a Virtual domain controller in Azure.

```
•   Azure Domain Services
```

If you have gone cloud only and deprecated your local AD, Azure offer Azure Domain Services. This is an Azure managed domain that is synced from Azure AD to Azure DS

http://www.tbone.se/2019/08/08/windows-virtual-desktop-part-2-requirements-and-infrastructure-setup/